# upload a video to my youtube from my laravel app and save the youtube video url to the database in youtube api v3

Tags: laravel, youtube, youtube-api, video-upload

i want it upload a video to youtube from my laravel app using the youtube API v3.I have read some blogs and am able to config the API credentials up to that point whereby I can be able to show the videos which are in my channel. but there is one part I have been unable to figure out how can I upload a video using a form in my app then the video is automatically saved in my youtube channel then get the URL of that video which I will then save it in the database.how can I make this possible. any clue fellow devs

Comment: @BenjaminLoison let me through it upclose